# How can I keep track of a list in discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

Here's my code

```
amount = 0
list = []
#b is the client
@b.command()
async def hello(ctx):
if list == []:
    list.append("9")
    list.append("10")
    list.append("11")
    list.append("12")
else:
    amount += 1
    print(list[amount])
```

So there's a couple things I want to do, every time I run the command through discord I want it to add 1 to the amount, I also want the things that I appended in the command to be permanently added to the list as those values will change every time I run the command.

This is an example of what I want to print out:

After I run it once:

```
9
```

After I run it twice:

```
10
```

After I run three times:

```
11
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like this? (dis.py questions arent necessarily accessible to test immediately)

```
lst = []
#b is the client
@b.command()
async def hello(ctx):
    if not lst:
        lst.append(9)
    else:
        last = lst[-1]
        await ctx.send(last)
        lst.append(last + 1)
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I've been on this for a while, I adapted your script and it worked awesome.

Comment: You're very welcome! If it helped you can always accept the answer for future users, happy coding!